# Determining equation of line from equidistant points in vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, vector-analysis

I have a question that gives three points (in 3d space). The task involves finding the equation of a line where the points are equidistant to that of the three given points.

The points given were $(3,1,2)$, $(1, -1, 2)$, and $(3,-1,4)$.

How would I go about solving this problem?

So far I've used the distance formula for each individual point with some point $(x,y,z)$ on the line. But I am unsure of where to go from there?

Comment: The line obviously has to be perpendicular to the plane containing the three points.

Comment: could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Draw a triangle on a sheet of paper.  Identify the circumcentre (the point that is equidistant to the three vertices).  Now imagine a line that is perpendicular to the paper that passes through the circumcentre.  Any point on that line is also equidistant to the three vertices.

Since you have three points, you can find the normal to the plane using the vector product.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Previous comment addressed the line's direction.  A point on the line (and in the plane) can be obtained by taking the arithmetic mean of the given points

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm not so sure that the arithmetic mean does.  That is, even in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the arithmetic mean gets you the coordinates of the centroid, not the circumcentre.

Comment: So in order to find the circumcentre, would you use the distance formula?

Comment: @AndrewChin:  maybe not in general, but in this particular case the points are equidistant from each other

Comment: @J.W.Tanner good eye.  In this case then, both the arithmetic mean and the equality of the expressions from the distance formula will get the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done.

The distance formula gives you two equalities and after squaring both sides and cancellation of squares you get two linear equations which are two planes and the intersection is the required line.

$$ (x-3)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-2)^2=(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2+(z-2)^2 $$

simplifies to $$x+y =2$$

and  $$ (x-3)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-2)^2=(x-3)^2+(y+1)^2+(z-4)^2 $$

simplifies to $$y-z=-3$$

The parametric equation of the line is  $$x=t, y=2-t,z=5-t$$

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to find the point in the plane through the points which is equidistant from them, ie the centroid. Then to take the normal to the plane through that point.

Label the points $A(3,1,2)$ and $B(1,-1,2)$ and $C(3,-1,4)$. The centroid is simply $(A+B+C)/3$ ie $(7/3,-1/3,8/3)$.

Notice that in all cases $x-y-z=0$. That is evidently the equation of the plane containing the points.

The normal to the plane through the origin is $(-t,t,t)$ (ie the parametric form, $t$ can take any value), so the normal through the circumcenter is the line $(7/3-t,-1/3+t,8/3+t)$ (again the parametric form).

Check: $AT^2=(3-7/3+t)^2+(1+1/3-t)^2+(2-8/3-t)^2=8/3+3t^2$

$BT^2=(1-7/3+t)^2+(-1+1/3-t)^2+(2-8/3-t)^2=8/3+3t^2$

$CT^2=(3-7/3+t)^2+(-1+1/3-t)^2+(4-8/3-t)^2=8/3+3t^2$

Comment: since the points are equidistant, you could have taken their arithmetic mean to get the center

Comment: What if the points were actually (2,1,3) (3,-4,-1),(2,1,-1)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes! Stupid of me. I am afraid I am a contest guy at heart, I tend to try to do things as fast as possible on this site, rather than as elegantly as possible. I have changed the method to your much more elegant approach. [I was dumb enough to calculate the sum of squares for each point from $(x,y,z)$ and solve the resulting equalities! But it did work, and fairly fast too!]

Answer (score 0):

Given two points $A$ and $B$, the locus of the set of points equidistant to them is the perpendicular bisecting plane of the line segment $AB$. For your three fixed points, then, the line of equidistant points is the intersection of the bisecting planes for each of the three possible pairs of points. This gives you a system of three linear equations, only two of which are independent. If you need to express the line in some other form (incidentally, there’s no such thing as *the* equation of a line), solve the system.